# URL redirect for Azure website

Tags: regex, .htaccess, azure, iis-7

I am trying to achieve a url redirect for canonical names ,in IIS , the thing is I am using Azure so it needs to be done in the web.config.

There are 2 domains www.**example**.com and www.**example1**.com , there is also a blog at www.example1.com/**blog** all the above urls **with our without www** need to redirect to www.**example1**.com and retain any text after the .com for blogs etc.

I am trying to  achieve the following but keep either failing to resolve the URL or an infinite loop , I am not too familiar with regex so can't seem to get everything working.

here is what I have so far

```
<rule name="Root Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example1.com/{R:0}" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>

                <rule name="www Redirect" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example1.com/{R:1}" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://example1.com" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
```

The above code works for all cases except 2 ( throws error in chrome) and 4 ( no redirect happening at all). Hope this helps and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

The rule to enforce www in the domain name:

```
<rule name="WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=" (.*)" />
  <conditions >
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The rule to redirect from another domain (escape all periods):

```
<rule name="Root Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www)?\.example\.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example1.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks @viperguynaz. I am still getting the same results using the code above. here are the cases where the regex fails , "http:// example.com" throws DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN and  "http:// example1.com" shows up as "http:// example1.com" instead of" www .example1.com" PS:- intentionally added spaces in url to show the url fully on the post

Comment: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN is fixed ... it was an issue and the DNS level where CNAME entry was missing.

Comment: move WWW after Root Redirect and change Roo Redirect's stopProcessing to false, then update WWW to just evaluate example1

Comment: Thanks viperguynaz, its fixed now. the order was the problem.